# Manage VirtualBox through VNC

Tags: linux, virtualbox, remote-desktop, fedora, vnc

I have a desktop computer running Fedora 24. I have installed VirtualBox 5.1 and configured a VNC Server to access remotely.

I am able to work with VirtualBox normally directly on the computer. Also I can connect remotely thru VNC (port 5902).

The problem is when I try to work with VirtualBox over VNC, the manager window doesn't show the menus correctly. For instance, when I click on **File**, the menu is empty

[File, Machine and Help are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMibc.png)

Also when trying to run from terminal in background im getting this error message:

```
[mario@mario ~]$ echo $DISPLAY
:2    
[mario@mario ~]$ VirtualBox &
[1] 10222
[mario@mario ~]$ Qt WARNING: QGtkStyle could not resolve GTK. Make sure you     have installed the proper libraries.
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
^C
```

Comment: Run VirtualBox inside the vnc session.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running virtual box via the command line using their command line utility: [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)